# R studio Mac Proxy issue

Tags: r, macos, proxy

I have downloaded and installed R  (3.4.1)and R studio (1.0.153) on MAC OS ( El Captain). I am facing trouble setting up the proxy. I am trying to install some packages from CRAN.

I referred to https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy

I was able to set up proxy and used properties
http_proxy=http://MYSERVER:MYPORT
http_proxy_user=user:passwd

I enabled options(internet.info = 0) option to get a trace of internet access from R Studio.
While the proxy server set up looks good in logs, its not able to get authentication.

Here are the logs:

```
Connected to MYSERVER  port MYPORT (#0)
> GET http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: cran.rstudio.com
User-Agent: R (3.4.1 x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 x86_64 darwin15.6.0)
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

* The requested URL returned error: 407 Proxy Authentication Required
* Closing connection 0
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

(Please note: I have replaced the proxy server and port )

I tried changing the 
http_proxy_user=ask

As suggested in one of the work around I read, but that also didn't work.

Could anyone suggest how to set up proxy authentication properly in R studio on Mac?

I have Eclipse installed on my local using the same proxy port and authentication and it is able to download stuff fine.

I am able to hit the url http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.gz directly in firefox.

Comment: You could try Sys.setenv(http_proxy="proxySettings") or httr package e.g. library(httr)
with_config(use_proxy(url="x",port, username="y",password="z"), install_github('byzheng/leafletplugins'))

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to make it work. The user id and password was accepted by adding them in the same property
http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyServer:port

This created another issue, my password contained @ char, which is why the proxy url was messed up. I referred to another post on stacktrace which suggested to try  urlencoding the "@" in the password to %40, With this change, it finally went through the proxy.

options(internet.info = 0) helped look through the detailed log which helped solve the issue.